# Make TAB work on the editor

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor, tabs-to-spaces

In the editor it'd be really nice if the tab key is trapped with JavaScript and is transferred to 4 space or similar so when I try to indent my code I can do it with one key. We have the code button but once that is applied it'd be nice to be able to style/indent the internal blocks easily.

(Hope that's not duplicate but even if it's it shows the need of such functionality)

Comment: @ChrisF the difference is I don't want to convert `pasted` TABs rather want to be able to press TAB while editing and that get translated to 4 spaces so the link you've posted is not quite relevant.

Comment: [I've posted a related discussion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234533/tab-functionality-in-se-when-editing-code-what-do-you-prefer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Very much no.

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key's behavior is very well-defined in a browser: It tabs you out of the editor box. Going with your feature request would mean killing functionality that everybody expects from their browser. This is not going to happen.

I have created [a user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts) offering the kind of functionality you want (check it out if you're a user script kind of person), and even there I added a way to go back to native tab behavior.

As you'll notice, that way is somewhat awkward. There really isn't a way to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> behave in both ways simultaneously, since they obviously contradict each other.

The "press and release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>" hack (or something along those lines) is okay for someone consciously making the decision to install a user script. But not for the core functionality of a website.

Comment: An alternative would be replace the `{}` with indent and unindent buttons, though I realise that might be quite a 'radical' change...

Comment: Why not [make it a user preference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293247/300504), off by default?

Comment: Yes, very much yes, please.