# Tab Key in Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

Is there a way I can enter the `Tab` key in Chat? I was actually posting some code in Chat, but it seems to be not indented at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd indent code the same way you do in a Markdown post on any Stack Exchange site, by using 4 spaces to indent.

And just like the post editor for answers and questions, the <kbd>TAB</kbd> is [not supported for indenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155270/make-tab-work-on-the-editor).