# Add tab input for code blocks

Tags: feature-request

Every time I input code into one of the Stack Exchange sites I automatically press <kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd></kbd> to shift the code to the right four spaces so it registers as code.

The tab input is not recognized and the dialog automatically loses focus. Having tab support would be helpful.

Comment: I don't disagree with this at all. But what you can do right now is: Input your code, then highlight it all and press Ctrl + K (or click the code button), and it will toggle indentation of the entire selected block. I suppose you could also surround it in `<pre>` tags but you'll lose syntax highlighting and also the semantic inaccuracy of the markup may keep you awake at night, if you're that kind of person.